# Copy Database from Server to Android

Tags: android, database, copy

i have a database on my webspace. Now i want to download this database and copy it into my /databases folder. It copies some parts of the DB but i can not access it. With "Root Explorer" it says "Error - An error occured while opening the database. unable to open the database file"

```
private final static String DB_NAME = "werweisswasquiz";
private final static String DB_PATH = "data/data/my-package-name/databases/";


try {
        // Log.d(TAG, "downloading database");
        URL url = new URL("http://unnediger.bplaced.net/Files/mydbfile");
    URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(1024);
    int current = 0;
    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
        baf.append((byte) current);
    }

    /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH+DB_NAME);
    myOutput.write(baf.toByteArray());
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    bis.close();
    is.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("DOWNLOAD", "downloadDatabase Error: ", e);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: yes some columns are encrypted. but not the whole database.

Comment: The database could not be opened from SQLite Manager as well. So I guess, you would have to decrypt the database or use the same decipher methods, that you used to encrypt the contents, to access them in Android.

Comment: but if i copy it from inside the /assets folder to the /databases it works. so i thought i could do this from a server also.

with the SQLiteManager for Mac i can open the database without any problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So i finally found the solution by myself.

The server thought that the file "mydbfile" is a txt file so i added the extention ".db" for sqlite database. now it works perfectly.